# In Postman, how do I take a response body from a Get Request, and put it in a PUT request with minor changes

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

I have ran a POST request to create a new contract. The Json response for this request was a string ID.

```
"03007"
```

My Post request has a test to save the response as an environment variable.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("newContractNb", jsonData);
```

I then have a GET request that plugs the response variable into the request so that I Get the data for the contract I created.

[image]

My Response is like so.

```
{
    "contractNb": "03007",
    "progSrvcNm": "009",
    "contractPrtyNm": "PostmanAutomationContract",
    "contractCd": "000",
    "signDt": "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
    "startDt": "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
    "endDt": "2025-01-01T00:00:00",
    "remitTerms": 30
}
```

I have a Test in the Get method to save this response body as a variable.

```
pm.environment.set('getRequestBody', pm.response.json())
```

Is it possible to then use this variable in the Body or Pre-req section of a PUT request, but somehow make it so that it alters a select parameter(s) - such as the contractPrtyNm only?

Comment: Yes but you would first need to either modify the response before setting it in a variable or in the pre-request script modify the variable re-set it then use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @Danny Dainton for the help!

My Get method after the post contained the following in order to save the response as a variable and edit it all in one.

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json()

jsonData.stuff = "PostmanAutomationContractEdit"
jsonData.otherStuff = 45
jsonData.altId1 = "AutoEdit"

function thing(id, classification, foo, foos, barf, contactNb) {
    this.id     = id
    this.classification = classification
    this.foo      = foo
    this.foos     = foos
    this.barf      = barf
    this.contactNb      = contactNb
}

let newThingData = new thing(pm.environment.get('newContractNb'), "bil", "y", "n", jsonData.thing[0].things, "000914")

jsonData.stuff[0].nextLevelStuff[0] = newPartyData

pm.environment.set('responseEdit', JSON.stringify(jsonData))
```

I then ran my PUT method with the variable in the body.

```
{{responseEdit}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the response from "{{url}}/{{newContractNb}}" you could try something like this. Modify the property then set the body in a request:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
jsonData.progSrvcNm = "blah"; 

pm.environment.set("response_b", jsonData);
```

Then in your PUT request (the type shouldn't matter) body just set it with

```
pm.environment.get("response_b");
```

Comment: Hey @so cal cheesehead, I attempted what you said. I saved the response from the Get and made edits as such 

var jsonData = pm.response.json();

jsonData.contractPrtyNm = "PostmanAutomationContractEdit";

jsonData.remitTerms = 45;

jsonData.altId1 = "AutoEdit";

pm.environment.set("responseEdit", jsonData);

I then entered the variable in the body of my PUT method
{{responseEdit}}

I get a 400 bad request - {
    "": [
        "The input was not valid."
    ]
}

Comment: I'm not sure if {{responseEdit}} will work in the body. Try using pm.environment.get("responseEdit") instead see if that works

Comment: It does not. It's showing a red x with a hover message of "Unexpected 'p' "

Comment: Actually it looks like {{responseEdit}} should work. I just tried it on a request and it worked fine. Can you confirm that the variable is been set properly? If you execute the requests manually, after you make the modifications and set the variable can you check in the "environment quick look" to make sure what's in the variable is what you expect?

Comment: my responseEdit variable is showing as [object Object] in the environment quick look. I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: It probably means the object is not getting stored the way you'd expect. I would suggest to use the console to log the object before and after modification then again in the pre-request script to see where things are going awry